# Cannot access nested JSON Object key : value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I assign a TypeScript object to a key (temp) of a nested JSON object (main):

```
weatherToday : any;

getTheWeather(city : String)
  {
    console.log("HOME.TS: Getting the weather...");
    this.weather.getWeather("Dublin").subscribe( data => {
      this.weatherToday = data.main.temp;

    });

  }
```

And then output the weatherToday object in home.html:

```
<p>{{weatherToday}}</p>
```

The output is as expected:
284.73

However when I try to assign the Typescript to the overall parent JSON object:

```
this.weatherToday = data;
```

And attempt to then output the same as above by object.object.value syntax in my home.html:

```
 <p>{{weatherToday.main.temp}}</p>
```

I get a exception:

> undefined is not an object

This is the JSON structure:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -121.94,
    "lat": 37.7
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 284.73,
    "feels_like": 282.68,
    "temp_min": 283.71,
    "temp_max": 286.48,
    "pressure": 1025,
    "humidity": 62
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.2,
    "deg": 63
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1608145061,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 4446,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1608131813,
    "sunset": 1608166239
  },
  "timezone": -28800,
  "id": 5344157,
  "name": "Dublin",
  "cod": 200
}
```

So I am not quite sure as to why this exception is thrown.
I am using Ionic v3.

Comment: Are you sure `weather.main.temp` exists for the city `"Dublin"` instead of using the passed in param? Could also do this in the template `<p>{{weatherToday?.main?.temp}}</p>`

Comment: @Passersby that works, what effect does the '?' have?

Comment: It will not try to access any deeper properties if the given parent is undefined/null

Comment: I see but if the variable does exists for given parent / child elements, which appears to be the case in this instance,  why would it not work without the '?'

Comment: I am guessing there is an error with binding. Could provide the folder that houses the html and TS along with the files themselves? My guess is something small that we are looking over.

Comment: Don’t understand the mark down, this seems to me to be a valid question, would be handy those doing the mark down could provide constructive feedback instead or with the mark down

Answer (score 2):

```
this.weather.getWeather("Dublin").subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherToday = data.main.temp;

    });
 <p>{{weatherToday}}</p>
```

Comment: This is what I have done in the first part of the question